# Copy a folder from USB to C Drive and then executing the install files using a script

Tags: windows-10, command-line, shell-script

I have been working on a way to copy a folder of files from a USB drive to the computers C drive. It is mostly straight forward but the USB drive's letter can change from computer to computer. So I have been trying to find a way to modify the script to account for this drive letter change.

```
MD C:\Placeforfiles
timeout /t 3
C:\WINDOWS\system32\xcopy.exe /S D:\Prep C:\Placeforfiles
timeout /t 5
C:\Placeforfiles\runall.bat
```

The D drive changes from computer to computer and so the copy fails. I have tried %~d0% and %CD:0,1% in place of D, I have tried setting a variable and using that. All fail on the xcopy command.

Another problem is the second script, runall.bat. At first I had it just run all the installers, but then in some instances I was going back and uninstalling software that wasn't needed or REMing out the stuff before running the script. So I added the yes/no inputs and broke the whole thing.

```
echo off
set /p chromeanswer=Install Chrome (Y/N)?
set /p scanswer=Install Screenconnect (Y/N)?
set /p officeanswer=Install M365 (Y/N)?
set /p readeranswer=Install Adobe Reader (Y/N)?
set /p dellanswer=Install Dell Support Assist (Y/N)?
set /p lenovoanswer=Install Lenovo System Update (Y/N)?
if /i "chromeanswer:~,1%" EQU "Y" START "" "C:\Placeforfiles\ChromeSetup.exe" & timeout /t 2
if /i "chromeanswer:~,1%" EQU "N" echo No Chrome
if /i "scanswer:~,1%" EQU "Y" START "" "C:\Placeforfiles\ConnectWiseControl.ClientSetup.msi" & timeout /t 2
if /i "scanswer:~,1%" EQU "N" echo No ScreenConnect
if /i "officeanswer:~,1%" EQU "Y" START "" "C:\Placeforfiles\OfficeSetup.exe" & timeout /t 2
if /i "officeanswer:~,1%" EQU "N" echo No M365
if /i "readeranswer:~,1%" EQU "Y" START "" "C:\Placeforfiles\readerdc_en_hi_install.exe" & timeout /t 2
if /i "readeranswer:~,1%" EQU "N" echo No Adobe Reader
if /i "dellanswer:~,1%" EQU "Y" START "" "C:\Placeforfiles\SupportAssistLauncher.exe" & timeout /t 2
if /i "dellanswer:~,1%" EQU "N" echo No Support Assist
if /i "lenovoanswer:~,1%" EQU "Y" START "" "C:\Placeforfiles\system_update_5.07.0110.exe" & timeout /t 2
if /i "lenovoanswer:~,1%" EQU "N" echo No Lenovo System Update
```

The reason for this is that some clients get Lenovo computer and others Dell. Additionally some prefer Adobe Reader, others prefer different programs. Basically I am trying to speed up my process a bit when preparing a computer. I know that there are ways to do things better, this is for one off cases and for my learning. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you launch the script from usb drive, you should be ok to use `\Prep` without the drive prefix `D:` and the path resolves on usb drive even if moved to E: later

Comment: If the script is on the drive in question.. then you simply refer to `%~DP0` to get your drive letter.  Perhaps there is something I don't understand.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - That did it, thanks.